# <p:ring> tag in PrimeFaces 3.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to create a Java web application based on JSF 2.0 and PrimeFaces 3.0
I have some problems with the  tag: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ring.jsf

Pictures that I used in the  tag are bigger then default limits and I can't reduce their size any more in order to keep them in a good resolution.
I tried to change width and height in many tags but nothing new 
So how can I modify the source code provided to use bigger photos in the ring tag???

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1. Override height attribute's value of ui-ring css style class. You can use a custom css file or an inline style tag with `.ui-ring { height: 18em; }` inside it.

Solution 2. use  style attribute setting the height directly `style="height: 18em !important;"` ( the !important may not be needed )

**UPDATED** May, 3

To enlarge the ring you can define a fixed width value using the style attribute. Component will adjust the distance between images automatically.
Ex.: `width: 100%;` or `width: 300px` or `width: 50em`

Unfortunately there's no way to adjust other options, but easing, of the Ring component.

Comment: Tanks Flavio for your answer, I tried these two solutions before but the first one have no effect in the ring element size and the second one modifies distance between rings and not the ring size!!!